# How to remove serverless dashboard?

Tags: serverless-framework

I've decided to try the new [Serverless framework dashboard](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/dashboard/) and now I just can't get rid of it. It's getting my CloudWatch logs and asking me to be logged in to be able to deploy, it's so annoying!

Does anyone know how to remove it? I can only find how to install it on their docs...

Answer (score 12):

Solved this issue by removing the `app` and `org` option son the `serverless.yml` file.

```
org: foo
app: foo-bar-api
service: foo-bar-api
...
```

Comment: This worked for me. The Serverless API was down and it prevented me from deploying. Decided to remove the dashboard after that.